# button not showing in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

btn3 is not showing when I run it in Netbeans.
when i ran it in NotePad it shows third button.
i cant really figure what the problem is.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Regform2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8;
    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf5, tf6, tf7;
    JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
    JPasswordField p1, p2;

    Regform2() {

        setTitle("Registration Form in Java");

        l1 = new JLabel("Registration Form in Windows Form:");
        l1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));

        l2 = new JLabel("Name:");
        l3 = new JLabel("Email-ID:");
        l4 = new JLabel("Create Passowrd:");
        l5 = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");
        l6 = new JLabel("Country:");
        l7 = new JLabel("State:");
        l8 = new JLabel("Phone No:");
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        p1 = new JPasswordField();
        p2 = new JPasswordField();
        tf5 = new JTextField();
        tf6 = new JTextField();
        tf7 = new JTextField();

        btn1 = new JButton("Submit");
        btn2 = new JButton("Clear");
        btn3 = new JButton("nxt");

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);

        l1.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);
        l2.setBounds(80, 70, 200, 30);
        l3.setBounds(80, 110, 200, 30);
        l4.setBounds(80, 150, 200, 30);
        l5.setBounds(80, 190, 200, 30);
        l6.setBounds(80, 230, 200, 30);
        l7.setBounds(80, 270, 200, 30);
        l8.setBounds(80, 310, 200, 30);
        tf1.setBounds(300, 70, 200, 30);
        tf2.setBounds(300, 110, 200, 30);
        p1.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 30);
        p2.setBounds(300, 190, 200, 30);
        tf5.setBounds(300, 230, 200, 30);
        tf6.setBounds(300, 270, 200, 30);
        tf7.setBounds(300, 310, 200, 30);
        btn1.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 30);
        btn2.setBounds(170, 350, 100, 30);
        btn3.setBounds(300, 350, 100, 30);
        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(tf1);
        add(l3);
        add(tf2);
        add(l4);
        add(p1);
        add(l5);
        add(p2);
        add(l6);
        add(tf5);
        add(l7);
        add(tf6);
        add(l8);
        add(tf7);
        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        add(btn3);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(700, 700);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btn1) {
            int x = 0;
            String s1 = tf1.getText();
            String s2 = tf2.getText();

            char[] s3 = p1.getPassword();
            char[] s4 = p2.getPassword();
            String s8 = new String(s3);
            String s9 = new String(s4);

            String s5 = tf5.getText();
            String s6 = tf6.getText();
            String s7 = tf7.getText();
            if (s8.equals(s9)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Data Saved Successfully");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Password Does Not Match");
            }



        } else if (e.getSource() == btn2) {
            tf1.setText("");
            tf2.setText("");
            p1.setText("");
            p2.setText("");
            tf5.setText("");
            tf6.setText("");
            tf7.setText("");


        } else {

            this.dispose();
            NewJFrame nw = new NewJFrame();
            nw.setVisible(true);


        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Regform2();
    }}
```

Comment: You're null layout isn't going to help. Between the frame been made visible and y calling setLayout, the container Amy be validated and the components laid out, which could be screwing with your attempt to do without it

Comment: You shouldn't `setLayout(null)`, but a `LayoutManager`, add to `getContentPane()` and call `pack` before making the `JFrame` visible.

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  That's the problem.  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: There's a (very good) reason why the JPasswordField returns a char array, I'd do some investigation into it and how you can use it to your advantage...

Comment: You example doesn't compile. `NewJFrame` isn't known. Please edit.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson   I removed setLayout(null)  it is giving wierd results everytime.

Comment: BTW - what is the intended layout of the buttons?  They seem to be 'left aligned' but I would expect them to be centered.

Comment: *"..it is giving wierd results everytime."*  There is more to using layouts than just **not** setting the layout to `null`.  Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @Karl Richter I did these changes on your suggestion

        this.pack();
        setVisible(true);
        //setLayout(null);

now it shows only btn3 in the entire window nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put setlayout(null) at first then setVisible(true),the btn3 will show in jframe. like this:

```
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(700, 700);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a JPanel. To this panel you add your components.
And don't forget to add your panel to your frame like this:

```
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    content.add(new JButton("Test"));

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
    this.setSize(Width, Height);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work... please define the codes of main frame at beginning of the 
constructor, such as  
`setTitle();
setSize();
setLayout();`

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Regform2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8;
JTextField tf1, tf2, tf5, tf6, tf7;
JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
JPasswordField p1, p2;

Regform2() {

    setTitle("Registration Form in Java");
    setSize(700, 700);
    setLayout(null);

    l1 = new JLabel("Registration Form in Windows Form:");
    l1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));

    l2 = new JLabel("Name:");
    l3 = new JLabel("Email-ID:");
    l4 = new JLabel("Create Passowrd:");
    l5 = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");
    l6 = new JLabel("Country:");
    l7 = new JLabel("State:");
    l8 = new JLabel("Phone No:");
    tf1 = new JTextField();
    tf2 = new JTextField();
    p1 = new JPasswordField();
    p2 = new JPasswordField();
    tf5 = new JTextField();
    tf6 = new JTextField();
    tf7 = new JTextField();

    btn1 = new JButton("Submit");
    btn2 = new JButton("Clear");
    btn3 = new JButton("Next");

    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    btn2.addActionListener(this);
    btn3.addActionListener(this);

    l1.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);
    l2.setBounds(80, 70, 200, 30);
    l3.setBounds(80, 110, 200, 30);
    l4.setBounds(80, 150, 200, 30);
    l5.setBounds(80, 190, 200, 30);
    l6.setBounds(80, 230, 200, 30);
    l7.setBounds(80, 270, 200, 30);
    l8.setBounds(80, 310, 200, 30);
    tf1.setBounds(300, 70, 200, 30);
    tf2.setBounds(300, 110, 200, 30);
    p1.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 30);
    p2.setBounds(300, 190, 200, 30);
    tf5.setBounds(300, 230, 200, 30);
    tf6.setBounds(300, 270, 200, 30);
    tf7.setBounds(300, 310, 200, 30);
    btn1.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 30);
    btn2.setBounds(170, 350, 100, 30);
    btn3.setBounds(290, 350, 100, 30);
    add(l1);
    add(l2);
    add(tf1);
    add(l3);
    add(tf2);
    add(l4);
    add(p1);
    add(l5);
    add(p2);
    add(l6);
    add(tf5);
    add(l7);
    add(tf6);
    add(l8);
    add(tf7);
    add(btn1);
    add(btn2);
    add(btn3);
    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btn1) {
        int x = 0;
        String s1 = tf1.getText();
        String s2 = tf2.getText();

        char[] s3 = p1.getPassword();
        char[] s4 = p2.getPassword();
        String s8 = new String(s3);
        String s9 = new String(s4);

        String s5 = tf5.getText();
        String s6 = tf6.getText();
        String s7 = tf7.getText();
        if (s8.equals(s9)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Data Saved Successfully");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Password Does Not Match");
        }



    } else if (e.getSource() == btn2) {
        tf1.setText("");
        tf2.setText("");
        p1.setText("");
        p2.setText("");
        tf5.setText("");
        tf6.setText("");
        tf7.setText("");


    } else {

        this.dispose();
        //NewJFrame nw = new NewJFrame();
        //nw.setVisible(true);


    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Regform2();
}
```

}